# how to open image as rgb file when using imageio

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, python-imageio

I have an existing code segment reading image using `scipy.misc`

```
imref = misc.imread(self.file_image, False, "RGB")
```

If I would like to replace it with imageio, how to do that, can I just use

```
imref = imageio.imread(self.file_image, False).
```

I am not clear where to setup the `"RGB"` parameter while using `imageio.imread`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As explained in the [docs](http://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scipy.html) you can use the keyword argument `pilmode` to specify the modality, while scipy `flatten` is replaced by `as_gray`. So in your case:

```
imref = imageio.imread(self.file_image, as_gray=False, pilmode="RGB")
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you get the error: "Imageio Pillow plugin requires Pillow lib"?